# Using Physics.OverlapBox in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game with Unity 2D, I want to find a list of objects in a square area. The documentation didn't explain well; it says that `Physics.OverlapBox` returns `Collider[]` and `Physics2D.OverlapBox` returns `bool`.

My question is:

> Can I use `Physics.OverlapBox` in Unity 2D? Will it work? If not, what should I use?

Answer (score 4):

## No

You need to use [Physics2D.OverlapBox()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html).

`Physics` is specifically the 3D physics engine and `Physics2D` is specificall the 2D physics engine. They do not work against each other.